# Django ORM .distinct() seems to return duplicate results

Tags: sql, django, sqlite, django-orm

I have an `Event` model that represents an Event happening. I have another `EventShow` model which represents a date and time that the event is taking place. Each event can have multiple shows, so I have a `ForeignKey` from `EventShow` to `Event` as follows -

```
class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    # ... and more

class EventShow(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='shows')
    start_date = models.DateTimeField()
```

I want to get a list of events which have at least one show happening in the future, so in my view I'm calling the ORM like this -

```
events = Event.objects.filter(shows__start_date__gt=now()).prefetch_related('shows').distinct().order_by('shows__start_date')
```

However, I still get the same event showing up multiple times if it has multiple shows. How can I fix this?

I looked at the SQL that was being generated by this call -

```
SELECT DISTINCT "core_event"."id", "core_event"."name", "core_eventshow"."start_date" 
  FROM "core_event" 
    INNER JOIN "core_eventshow" ON ("core_event"."id" = "core_eventshow"."event_id") 
  WHERE ("core_eventshow"."start_date" > 2023-08-16 02:48:46.063093) 
  ORDER BY "core_eventshow"."start_date" ASC
```

I'm using SQLite for development.

Comment: I think you are using a related manager in a queryset so instead of `shows` in filter it should be `eventshow` replace `shows` with `eventshow` but not in prefetch

Comment: _I'm using SQLite for development_ - and I really hope that's for production too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you have the `"core_eventshow"."start_date"` in your `SELECT` clause because of your `.order_by`. This causes every row selected to be *distinct* from each other.

Removing the `.order_by` should fix this as it doesn't serve any useful purpose anyway.

Alternatively you can use PostgreSQL with its [`DISTINCT ON` support](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/querysets/#distinct):

> On PostgreSQL only, you can pass positional arguments (*fields) in order to specify the names of fields to which the DISTINCT should apply. This translates to a SELECT DISTINCT ON SQL query. Here’s the difference. For a normal distinct() call, the database compares each field in each row when determining which rows are distinct. For a distinct() call with specified field names, the database will only compare the specified field names.

Comment: I added the order_by because I want to order the events by whichever one has a show starting the earliest. If I remove the order_by, the events are returned in the order which they were created. How should I order the selected events by the start date of their earliest show in that case?

Comment: You can't do that in a single query even with `DISTINCT ON`. Consider using a [`Subquery`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions).